# Memory leak on DSBezelActivityView

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uiactivityindicatorview

I got a UIWebView in my project with DSBezelActivityView but it seems to have a memory leak. I use the DSBezelActivityView for when the page is loading. It works as it should beside the memory leak. How do I solve this memory leak?

I used this code:
http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview

This is what analyzer says:
Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.be"];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
webView.delegate = self;

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[DSBezelActivityView newActivityViewForView:aiv withLabel:@"Laden..." width:90];
NSLog(@"werkt dit");

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[DSBezelActivityView removeView];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're leaking the object returned by `newActivityViewForView:withLabel:width`.

According to Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html):

> **You own any object you create**
>
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for
>   example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

So you need to release the object at a proper moment, I think it is the  `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. Your code should be something like these:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    DSBezelActivityView *bezelActivityView = [DSBezelActivityView newActivityViewForView:aiv withLabel:@"Laden..." width:90];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [DSBezelActivityView removeView];
    [bezelActivityView release];
    bezelActivityView = nil;
}
```

I don't this `DSBezelActivityView` class so my answer is based on the Cocoa Memory Management Conventions. Keep in mind that could have created a method starting with *new* that does not follow the convention.